# Create C# unit test, Out parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods

```
public static double Add(out double sum, double summandOne,double sumandTwo )
{
    sum = summandOne + sumandTwo;
    return sum;
}
```

Task: The created methods are completely covered by unit tests (100% code coverage)

hey guys how can i create a unit test for this method?

I tried but unfortunately it's not correct

```
[TestMethod()]
public void AddTest(out double sum, double sumOne, double sumTwo)
{
  sum = sumOne + sumTwo;
  program.Add(out sum, sumOne, sumTwo);
  Assert.AreEqual(25, 20,5);
}
```

Comment: What's "not correct" about it?  In what way does this code fail?  Which *specific operation* doesn't produce the result you expect?  What result does it produce?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MSTest, it needs to be:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(25.0, 20.0, 5.0)]
public void AddTest(double expected, double val1, double val2)
{
  double sum = 0;
  program.Add(out sum, val1, val2);
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, sum);
}
```

Not sure where you defined "program", though.